# Plotband needs to be displayed on few data sets in a series on X axis High gantt chart

Tags: highcharts, gantt-chart

I am trying to show plotband on x axis but its getting displayed on all x axis data series. I want to render it for certain x axis values only. I
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by adding white plotBands on the yAxis (to cover the common part from the xAxis).

```
xAxis: {
    min: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 17),
    max: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 30),
            plotBands: [{
                from: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 18),
                to: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 20)
            }]
},
    
    yAxis: {
        plotBands: [{
            from: 0.5,
            to: 1.5,
            color: 'white'
        }]
    },
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nzk3mjg8/

Comment: Thanks for reply. In your solution, Plotband is fixed on all y axis except the one having white color. I wanted to show it in such a way that all Y axis having different plotbands range. Example - y1 having range 1 Nov to 5 Nov, y2 having 10 Nov to 12 Nov etc. I should have mentioned in question properly. 
But i have done it with extending high chart classes.